# Django Oauth Toolkit 2-legged and 3-legged

Tags: django, python-2.7, oauth, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I have been searching on the internet but haven't been able to find this answer.

Basically i want to know if Django Oauth Toolkit supports both 2-legged and 3-legged approach and if so, how do i use it exactly??

I am using it with Django Rest Framework.

I think their official documentation example suggests they are using a 2-legged approach, but is it possible to use a 3-legged??

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Django Oauth Toolkit Official documentation example are mostly 3-legged(token used). 2-legged is something like you register an app in facebook/twitter and get api key and secret. Then you use those(key, secret) on your client app to access protected resources(no token is used).

Ref: https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html

Register an application part and use those key, secret on oauth toolkit you can call 2-legged

Step 4-5 example of 3-lagged.